# How can I change my regEx so that it is correctly applied to the URLs I'm trying to scrape?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium for this and my code is the following:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
omegaBase = "https://www.omegawatches.com/de/"          
productRegex = re.compile(r'[https://](w){3}')

driver.get(omegaBase + "watches/" + "constellation")
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for link in links:
    pageUrls = link.get_attribute("href")
    print(pageUrls)
    productRegex.findall(pageUrls)
```

If I comment out the regEx and just `print(pageUrls)` I get all the links on the page, which is fine, but I'm trying to get only a select few specific links from the page in the format `https://www.omegawatches.com/de/watch/name_of_product`

I'm not that great using Regular Expressions, I definitely need to practice and learn more but I've been playing around just to see if it will apply at all and I keep getting the error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Does anyone know how I can fix the regEx, so that it is at least applied correctly? The regEx I am using in the above example is only really to remove a couple of links so I can see that it is working at least.

Comment: When you're scraping HTML regex is the last thing you need to use... There are enough Selenium built-in methods and properties to do required job for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex to do what you are attempting. You can use a simple CSS selector.

```
a[href^='https://www.omegawatches.com/de/watches/']
```

This just looks for an `A` tag that has an href that starts with the URL you want.

You can further modify this to focus on specific links, like only the watch links in the footer, e.g.

```
div.footer-main-table a[href^='https://www.omegawatches.com/de/watches/']
```

...and so on

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate a bit? I haven't used selenium a lot for this kind of thing and I guess I would need to use driver.find_elements_by_css_selector

Comment: @LRBrady , try `pageUrls = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='https://www.omegawatches.com/de/watches/']")]`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's look at your regular expression. You're doing this:

```
productRegex = re.compile(r'[https://](w){3}')
```

When you're building a regular expression, things in square brackets match one of the set of characters which it includes. For example, `[aeiou]` matches `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u` only. Here you want to match the string `https://` so just put it in without square brackets:

```
productRegex = re.compile(r'https://(w){3}')
```

You could change it further by using `^` to match just the beginning of the expression, and simplify `(w){3}` to `www`:

```
productRegex = re.compile(r'^https://www')
```

---

Now let's look at how you're using your regular expression:

```
for link in links:
    pageUrls = link.get_attribute("href")
    print(pageUrls)
    productRegex.findall(pageUrls)
```

Here you're getting the linked URL using `get_attribute()`. This gets the one URL, so I'd suggest changing the variable name from `pageUrls` to `pageUrl`. Then you'll need to check whether the URL matches the regular expression, which you do like this:

```
if productRegex.match(pageUrl):
    print(pageUrl)
else:
    print('No match')
```

(Of course, now we've got this far, we note that we don't need `^` in the regular expression if we're using `match()` which only looks for a match at the beginning of the string.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know, I'll change that now. Do you know how I would get around the error that I am getting? obviously what I wrote is iterating over all the links on the page and returning them and this isn't a "string or bytes-like character"

Comment: Out of curiosity, when using that regex, why not just check if the string startswith `https://www`?

Comment: I was going to do that, but first I wanted to test that the regex was even being applied first. There was a Nonetype object in the middle being returned that was causing problems.